# WebDriver - Google Chrome does not click element from time to time, but no error is present

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, click, webdriver

Did you ever experience problems with Google Chrome, which would sometimes click an element and sometimes would not? Without throwing any errors of course... I know that the part of code responsible for clicking on the element is executed without any visible problems (logger, which is one line after the click reports the click). Browser window is maximized and zoom level is 100%, the element doesn't move after the page has been loaded, it is not overlapped by any other element...

Also it only happens in a 4 tests, which use one single class and happens only with one particular checkbox. To make it stranger there is another checkbox on the site under test, just belo the problematic onew, which always works fine. The HTML code for both checkboxes is the same, the only difference being the value of "name" attribute.

Here's the page source (it's the first checkbox that gives me trouble):

```
<div class="checkbox elementdbl">
     <input id="acceptterms" type="checkbox" value="1" name="acceptterms">
     <label for="acceptterms">Some text</label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox elementdbl">
     <input id="acceptpermit" type="checkbox" value="1" name="acceptpermit">
     <label for="acceptpermit">Some other text</label>
 </div>
```

Software versions:

- Java 7
- Selenium Hub & Grid 2.43.1
- Google Chrome 38
- GoogleChromeDriver 2.12

I've been able to workaround the issue with substituting click event with sendKeys(Keys.SPACE) method, which so far works fine. But I hate workarounds as such, so maybe you have any ideas on what might be causing this Google Chrome-specific behaviour?

Cheers,
Bartek

Comment: Back when I use IBM's Rational Function Tester for web testing, and when using Selenium this same issue occurred from time to time. I think it is just how Chrome renders the elements.

Comment: But ain't that strange that it only happens to one single element? We have around 300 tests, which are run on Google Chrome and the issue is present (so far at least!) only for one single checkbox...

Comment: It is a group of checkboxes? While writing tests I was never able to change the layout of the page, maybe you can. I always wondered if the page orientation of the checkboxes made a difference. Maybe something to look at.

Comment: No, it is not a group. I've updated to issue with the source code. Take a look.

Comment: It happens not only on Chrome, on IE too. Could be caused by some javasript code that manipulates DOM while loading the page, could be a bug in chrome/ie driver or in WebRdiver ? Who knows? It happens from time to time and we must live with it, in my tests there is some nasty link - I click it, and I am checking if it fired, if no then I click it again in a loop, sometimes even 3 times.

Comment: Uh, that's one way to do it. With checkboxes it is trickier as most of the time after checking them the attribute "checked" remains unset, but maybe method isSelected() could work in such case and return current state of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen is that Chrome has a problem clicking on some elements. It positions the pointer in the "middle" of the element, but if the element has text -- especially on multiple lines -- there's a bit of that area that is actually not clickable.

There's a Chrome bug on this which I found some time back but can no longer find.  However, if you [go to this link](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2766) and read through lukela's comments, about 2/3 of the way down he describes this situation in some detail.

Hope this helps; at least you know you're not going crazy :=0